# What graphics driver should I get from AMD if I have an R9 290 and an AMD A10-5800K APU

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card

So I recently got a ASUS AMD R9 290 with 4GB GDDR5 memory and when I installed the driver from the disk it caused my windows 10 installation to become completely unusable (it would just hang when booting), so I have installed Windows 8.1. The driver works just fine on Windows 8.1 so it must have had a compatibility issue with windows 10.

However the driver which is installed is an old driver (2013/14) and when doing certain tasks the card will cause my screen to glitch (I have reason to believe this is because of the driver). When I visit AMD's website they have drivers for the R9 series and the APU series.. I have an AMD A10-5800K APU as well as this R9 card and I am very unsure about which driver I should install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct driver to install was the R9 290 driver, I made a restore point installed it and it has solved the issues of the screen glitching and made the card stable at 119-123fps on Furmark.